# Autocorrelation with cupy

Tags: python, gpu, cupy, autocorrelation

I want to calc the autocorrelation of an image on a GPU.
However, when I use the cupy correlate function, I get a different result than for the CPU calculation. Is it because cupyx.scipy.ndimage.correlate automatically normalizes the result by the autocorrelation of a uniform image?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sc
import cupy as cp
import cupyx.scipy.ndimage as cnd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ones = np.ones((128,128))

corr_cpu = sc.correlate2d(ones,ones)
corr_gpu = cnd.correlate(cp.array(ones),cp.array(ones))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(corr_cpu)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Correlation CPU')

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(cp.asnumpy(corr_gpu))
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Correlation GPU')
plt.show()
```

[CPU result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MQwH.png)

[GPU result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfXLr.png)

Comment: Does the discrepancy persist if for the CPU computation you use `scipy.ndimage.correlate` rather than `scipy.signal.correlate2d`?

Comment: yes scipy.signal.correlate gives the same result as correlate2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay found the answer:
cupyx.scipy.ndimage.correlate uses mode='reflect' as default, whereas scipy.correlate uses 'constant'.

So 'constant' for cupy gives now the same result as the scipy function

Comment: Btw: scipy.ndimage.correlate also uses mode='reflect' as default...